# Zoom to Openlayers 3 function

Tags: javascript, zooming, openlayers-3, getview

I'm using this function from Openlayers 3 cookbook:

```
function zoomTo() {
  map.beforeRender(
    ol.animation.pan({
      source: map.getView().getCenter(),
      duration: 150
    }),

    ol.animation.zoom({
      resolution: map.getView().getResolution(),
      duration: 500,
      easing: ol.easing.easeIn
    })
  );
  map.getView().fit(Houses1860b.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());

}
```

This function works great but, the zoom is closer to the feature than I need and I would like to know if there is another way to do a zoom to the feature, but with one or two zoom levels less than this function does.

I assume it's possible to make another new variable called "extension" and add values to `Houses1860b.getSource().getExtent()` for doing the extension bigger than by default... I look for posts with this info but I didn't found none, Can you help me?

Comment: You can use **padding** options in the  [ol.view.fit](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, my appologies, I don't know exactly where I have to add this padding options. I try changing by "source:  map.getView().fit(Houses1860b.getSource().getExtent(), padding[0,0,0,0]" and also I try this in the last line (changing padding[] by map.getSize). Those changes don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give an example by considering, **100px padding in all directions(top, right, bottom and left)**. Then I will have that feature in below way.

```
function zoomTo() {
    map.beforeRender(
        ol.animation.pan({
           source: map.getView().getCenter(),
           duration: 150
        }),

        ol.animation.zoom({
           resolution: map.getView().getResolution(),
           duration: 500,
           easing: ol.easing.easeIn
        })
    );
    map.getView().fit(Houses1860b.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize(), {
        padding : [100, 100, 100, 100]
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, padding was not the solution, you are not allowed to do zoom out, only zoom in, then the view is closer to the map and I need just the opposite.
My solution was with "maxZoom" like this:

map.getView().fit(Houses1860b.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize(), {
           maxZoom: 18});


maxZoom instead padding, now I can stablish a view further, and show smaller objects on the map,

Thanks a lot, I didn't know how to write the code right, your answer was usefull! :D